# QuickContactBadge on an unknown contact

Tags: android, contacts

I'm downloading a list of contacts from a company website.  The contacts may or may not be on the phone.  I'd like to use the QuickContactBadge since the downloaded information will contain: office phone number, mobile number, email, name.  This way users can quickly view and contact the people listed on the company website or add them to their list of phone contacts.

All the examples show how to use existing contacts.

When I want to add an unknown contact name, email and phone numbers I call from my listview adapter:
QuickContactBadge badge = (QuickContactBadge) baseAct.findViewById(R.id.badge_small);
badge.assignContactFromPhone("888-555-1212", true);

but it crashes on assignContactFromPhone.

Can I use the quick contact badge for this or should I just create a separate view that has a button for phone, email, and importing a contact?

SamB

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [this](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/contacts/ui/QuickContactActivity.java.html). As QuickContacts refer to the RawContacts.CONTENT_URI : prior querying it you should add those contacts to this provider, or work around with the source to get your own version !